# cloudformation multiple if conditions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have conditions

```
Red: !Equals [!Ref Color,Red]
Blue: !Equals [!Ref Color,Blue]
Green: !Equals [!Ref Color,Green]
Orange: !Equals [!Ref Color,Orange]
```

At the moment, I am using an If statement with 2 conditions.
Properties:
Name: !If [Red,!Sub 'I choose Red','I choose Blue']

How can I have the name attribute with multiple if clause to represend all of them?

Like this

```
  If Red
     "Red"
  else if "Blue"
     "Blue"
  else if "Green"
     "Green"
etc..
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this via nested `If` functions, i.e. the "else" value resolves to the value of another `If` function:

```yaml
!If
- Red
- "Red"
- !If
  - Blue
  - "Blue"
  - !If
    - Green
    - "Green"
    - !Ref AWS::NoValue # if none of the above conditions match
```

(I'm not 100% sure the shorthand `!If` syntax will work nested like that but I suspect it will. Otherwise just change it to the longhand `Fn::If:`.)